# ListViewItem Checked vs. Selected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

For which actions should I use `Checkbox` vs. `SelectedItem` of a `ListViewItem`? I can't help but think that it just comes down to personal preference, but then again, I still don't *know*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A checked item won't loose its "check" if you select other items. Selected items can be grouped using control/shift, but when you click on another item without shift/control, all other items will be deselected.

I think its safe to assume that the checked items are a more persistent experience. It can only be undone by physically "un" checking it.

Comment: Good point. Now I am wondering if I should bother with CheckBoxes or not. I get that they're more persistent and it's easier to select multiple items, but that means I'll basically be reusing code just for the sake of having one extra method of selection. I do like having those CheckBoxes there, though...

Comment: Its all about user experience, give the user the best possible experience concerning the task they have to complete. The cost of having code for both scenarios far outweigh benefits that could be added (If check boxes are indeed applicable to your application experience). You should make that decision.